# arrow operator not returning a function

Tags: javascript

I am a newbie at this es6 convention, have been out of touch with js for a few years.

### What works

Only this works --

```js
const apiClient = create({
  baseURL: "http://" + IP + ":8990",
  headers: { Authorization: "auth_token" },
});
```

The above script is imported in **getPosts.js** :

```js
import { apiClient } from "./client";
const endpoint = "/api/";
const getPosts = () => {
  return apiClient.get(endpoint);
};
```

---

### Problem

---

However when I try importing any of the following in **getPosts.js**, it says :

`TypeError: _client.apiClient.get is not a function.`

```js
const apiClient = (auth_token="") => {
  create({
    baseURL: "http://" + IP + ":8990",
    headers: { Authorization: auth_token },
  });
};
```

---

```js
const apiClient = () => {
  return create({
    baseURL: "http://" + IP + ":8990",
    headers: { Authorization: "auth_token" },
  });
};
```

---

```js
const apiClient = () =>
  create({
    baseURL: "http://" + IP + ":8990",
    headers: { Authorization: "auth_token" },
  });
```

This is the whole file :

```js
import { create } from "apisauce";
import IP from "../config/network";

const apiClient = create({
  baseURL: "http://" + IP + ":8990",
  headers: { Authorization: "auth_token" },
});

const setAuthToken = (token) => {
  return console.log("in setAuthToken : " + token);
};

export { apiClient, setAuthToken };
```

I am doing this because I want to pass a parameter to the function.
Thanks.

Comment: `setAuthToken` is not doing anything except logging - not sure if this is intentional

Comment: That is because in those other cases `apiClient` is a function not the return value of the `create` function, you'll have to use something like `apiClient().get(endpoint)` or `apiClient(token).get(endpoint)`

Comment: Have added that just for testing, it had a whole functionality, removed here for brevity

Comment: @Titus thanks, that worked. it was silly of me. Please submit that as an answer, will accept that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, `apiClient` is set to the return value of the `create` function which seems to be an object that has a `get` property, in those other cases, `apiClient` is set to a function that returns the return value of `create`.

You'll have to use something like this:

```
apiClient().get(endpoint)
```

OR

```
apiClient(token).get(endpoint)
```